# criteriaBuilder notEqual fuction doesnt return null values for manyToOne class

Tags: java, jpa, criteria, predicate, hibernate-criteria

I have two classes like below

```
public class User {

    @Column(name = "EMP_NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "EMP_PASSWORD")
    private String password;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private Role role;
    ....
}

public class Role {

    @column("ROLE_NAME")
    private String name;

    @column("IS_MASTER")
    String isMaster; // 'Y' or 'N'
    ...
}
```

I need to get all users which is not master or dont have role. For do this I try something like that but not working.

```
Predicate nonMaster =  cb.notEqual(root.get("role").get("isMaster"), "Y");
cb.and(nonMaster)
```

but this is not returning users which don't have role value (ROLE_ID == NULL). I also try this but also not work.

```
Predicate nonMaster =  cb.notEqual(root.get("role").get("isMaster"), "Y");
Predicate nullRole =  cb.isNull(root.get("role"));
cb.or(nullRole,nonMaster);
```

How can I make a query like role is null or role.isMaster equal to "N"

Answer (score 0):

for fix this problem I make my query left join. With this I able to take empty values.

```
Root<User> root = q.from(User.class);
root.join(User_.role,JoinType.LEFT);
```